# Как определить размер файла, имея только список его байтов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется список байтов файла. Полученные, допустим, таким образом:

```
def get_byte_file(abs_path):
    with open(abs_path, "rb") as f:
        return f.read().decode("latin1")
```

Вопрос стоит в том, как получить размер файла, имея только результат данной функции

Comment: Просто `len(результат)` же?

Comment: @andreymal получится в байтах?

Comment: В кодировке latin1 один байт соответствует одному unicode-символу, так что да

Comment: не самое быстрое решение смотреть размер файла путём его полного считывания